# How to catch events (if available) for a GeoJSON feature in Leaflet?

Tags: events, leaflet, event-handling, geojson

I have the following polygon:

```
var feature_polygon = {
    "type": "Feature",
    "properties": {
        "name": "GeoJSON Example",
        "popupContent": "This is an example for a GeoJSON feature with Polygon geometry"
    },
    "geometry": {
        "type": "Polygon",
        "coordinates": [
          [
            [
              2.338451,
              30.018958
            ],
            [
              2.338451,
              30.070397
            ],
            [
              2.435097,
              30.070397
            ],
            [
              2.435097,
              30.018958
            ],
            [
              2.338451,
              30.018958
            ]
          ]
        ]
    }
};
```

I am adding the feature to my Leaflet map by doing

```
L.geoJSON(feature_polygon, {
    onEachFeature: onEachFeature
}).addTo(map);
```

where

```
function onEachFeature(feature, layer) {
    // does this feature have a property named popupContent?
    if (feature.properties && feature.properties.popupContent) {
        layer.bindPopup(feature.properties.popupContent);
    }
}
```

Currently this allows me to display a popup balloon using the `properties` data provided by the GeoJSON feature.

My goal is for the map to be synchronized with a PostGIS database (all interconnected using Django) incl. updates to and deletion of existing as well as creation of new DB entries. In order for me to do that I need to capture any `remove`, `create`, `edit` and so on event and "convert" those events to REST calls (for Django to process).

If I were to use the usual drawing in Leaflet for e.g. a polygon I would be able to do

```
feature.on('edit', function() {
    console.log('Polygon was edited!');
})
```

If I were to create the geometry (not a feature!) through the Geoman plugin, I would be able to do

```
map.on('pm:create', ({layer}) => {
    layer.on('pm:edit', e => {
        console.log('Geoman edit action: edit');
        console.log(e);
    });
  
    layer.on('pm:cut', e => {
        console.log('Geoman edit action: cut');
        console.log(e)
    })
  
    layer.on('pm:drag', e => {
        console.log('Geoman edit action: drag');
        console.log(e)
    })
    
    layer.on('pm:dragend', e => {
        console.log('Geoman edit action: dragend');
        console.log(e)
    })
});
```

even though this (at least for me) is a one time thing (e.g. any cutting of a polygon after the first one does not trigger the handler...).

I do know that editing (cutting, rotating, dragging) is working with GeoJSON since...well, it does. :D I am using the Geoman plugin to do the editing even though the feature itself was added through code. I am almost certain I need to work with `onEachFeature()` but not sure what exactly needs to be done.